# xslt assigning variable value to string literal

Tags: xslt

I have

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
  <xsl:variable name="expression" select="name()" ></xsl:variable>
</xsl:for-each>
```

below I have href and i want to set the value this expression variable in href #######

```
<a href="/myplan?expression={$expression}" class="deleteIcon">Delete</a>
```

I also tried with :

```
  <a href="concat('/myplan?expression={',$expression)}" class="deleteIcon">Delete</a>
```

None of them worked.

Can Anybody help me out how to do that?

Basically my task is to find the expression for current node and send the expression for the same in href?

Adding More Info :

```
<br/><xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
               <xsl:variable name="expression" select="name()" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        <b><a href="{concat('/admin/eapp/deleteQuestions?expression=',$expression)}"></a>Click Me</b>
```

when above xsl code is transformed it is giving below error:

```
 Variable or parameter 'expression' is undefined.
```

Comment: When you say that something doesn't work, always say exactly what you did and exactly what the effect was. We can't diagnose a problem without knowing the symptoms. And don't just show the code that doesn't work: explain what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I have deleted my previous answer, as the new information made it irrelevant. Instead, it looks like you want expression to contain a concatenated list of all ancestor names, but I am not sure. Can you post a sample input XML, and also your expected output, so there is not doubt? Thanks.

Comment: My requirement is : i want to send the path of current node from root node to the server so that i can use this path to delete the node. For Example. delete 5th subcatagory of 3rd catagory from the xml.   So what i am doing is i am iterating over catagory and inside catagory there is another iterator over subcatagorie . Now I want to find xpath of node in this subcatagory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, variables are scoped in XSL and exist only within the containing tag.  Thus the variable named `expression` exists only within the `for-each` block.  Also, variables can only be set once.  Attempting to set a variable value a second time has no effect.

Therfore you have to declare the variable at or above the level where you want to use it, and put all the code to generate the value inside the variable declaration.  If you can use XSLT2, the following will do what you want:

```
string-join(for $n in ancestor-or-self::* return name($n), '/')
```

I know it can also be done in XSLT 1 with a recursive template, but I don't have an example handy.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT1.0, you could try setting the variable like so:

```
  <xsl:variable name="expression">
     <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
```

So, assuming the following XML structure

```
<As>
   <a>
      <Bs>
         <b>5</b>
      </Bs>
   </a>
   <a>
      <Bs>
         <b>9</b>
      </Bs>
   </a>
   <a/>
   <a>
      <Bs>
         <b>12</b>
         <b>14</b>
         <b>15</b>
      </Bs>
   </a>
</As>
```

If you were positioned on the **b** element with the value of 14, then **expression** would be set to **/As/a/Bs/b**

However, this does not take into account multiple nodes with the same name, and so would not be sufficient if you wanted accurate XPath to select the node.

Instead, you could try the following:

```
  <xsl:variable name="expression">
     <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = $name]) + 1"/>
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
```

This would return **/As[1]/a[4]/Bs[1]/b[2]**, which may be what you want.